# When Accessing the Routes Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag::get(): Argument #1 ($key) must be of type string, null given, error is thrown.,,

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag::get(): Argument #1 ($key) must be of type string, null given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\laravelprojects\burgerStation\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php on line 160

This is the Error
Help Need.

TypeError
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag::get(): Argument #1 ($key) must be of type string, null given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\laravelprojects\burgerStation\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php on line 160
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Stack trace
Request
App
User
Context
Debug
Share

Collapse vendor frames
34
D:\xampp\htdocs\laravelprojects\burgerStation\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\InputBag.php
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag
:30
33
D:\xampp\htdocs\laravelprojects\burgerStation\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php
Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession
:160
32
:263
31
Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession
:161
30
Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession
:57
29
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
28
Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse
:37
27
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
26
Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies
:67
25
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
24
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:103
23
Illuminate\Routing\Router
:697
22
Illuminate\Routing\Router
:672
21
Illuminate\Routing\Router
:636
20
Illuminate\Routing\Router
:625
19
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel
:167
18
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:128
17
Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies
:39
16
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
15
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest
:21
14
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull
:31
13
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
12
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest
:21
11
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings
:40
10
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
9
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize
:27
8
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
7
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance
:86
6
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
5
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:103
4
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel
:142
3
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel
:111
2
:52
1
:21
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag::get
D:\xampp\htdocs\laravelprojects\burgerStation\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\InputBag.php:30

/**

- InputBag is a container for user input values such as $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST, and $_COOKIE.
- 
- @author Saif Eddin Gmati azjezz@protonmail.com

*/

final class InputBag extends ParameterBag

{

```
/**

 * Returns a scalar input value by name.

 *

 * @param string|int|float|bool|null $default The default value if the input key does not exist

 *

 * @return string|int|float|bool|null

 */

public function get(string $key, $default = null)

{

    if (null !== $default && !is_scalar($default) && !(\is_object($default) && method_exists($default, '__toString'))) {

        trigger_deprecation('symfony/http-foundation', '5.1', 'Passing a non-scalar value as 2nd argument to "%s()" is deprecated, pass a scalar or null instead.', __METHOD__);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can make sure if the `$key` is not null either:

```
public function get(string $key = null, $default = null)

{
    if ($key !== null && null !== $default ...
```